# Deploy of Azure Logic App requires service bus connection string even with configured api connection

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I am building a Logic App with connection to Service Bus. I created the Logic App and the API Connection. To the API connection I added the Service Bus RootManageSharedAccessKey primary connection string. I can use that API connection in the Trigger action of new message appearing in the queue.

Now, if I load the logic app to Visual Studio and deploy it from there (using the Resource Group project type) it asks for the Service Bus connection string.

[image]

In the above picture I have used the keyvault. It creates following LogicApp.parameters.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "value": "publisher-la-messagebatcher-test"
    },
    "servicebus_1_connectionString": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/publisher-kvault-test"
        },
        "secretName": "servicebus-connection-string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, my question is why do I have to provide the connection string again in the logic app deployment parameters for the API connection (in this case "publisher-sb-test-connection")? Isn't it enough that the connection itself (in Azure) is configured to use the connection string? Can I bypass defining the connection string in the logic app deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it. Visual Studio creates the API connection also to the template. Open the LogicApp.json and remove the servicebus_1_connectionString resource creation logic.

```
"servicebus_1_connectionString": {
  "type": "securestring",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Azure Service Bus Connection String"
  }
},
---
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('servicebus_1_Connection_Name'))]"
  ]
},
{
  "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('servicebus_1_Connection_Name')]",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'westeurope', '/managedApis/', 'servicebus')]"
    },
    "displayName": "[parameters('servicebus_1_Connection_DisplayName')]",
    "parameterValues": {
      "connectionString": "[parameters('servicebus_1_connectionString')]"
    }
  }
```